# NameError when assigning function argument to dynamically created class's attribute of the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I came across a piece of strange behaviour whilst trying to create a dynamic class inside a function. When I try to assign a function argument to a class attribute of the same name, a `NameError` is raised. I can get around this by changing one of the names, but I'm confused as to why this is happening in the first place. (I'm using Python 3.8.2)

```
def f(i):
    class G:
        i = i
    return G

def x(a):
    class Y:
        b = a
    return Y
```

And the result in the shell:

```
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in G
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> x(1)
<class '__main__.x.<locals>.Y'>
```

Comment: Add a `nonlocal i` to the beginning of `class G`.

Comment: @martineau Ah, silly me, I should have seen that. But is there a reason why this doesn’t occur when the name being assigned to is different to the parameter name?

Comment: It doesn't happend because there's no ambiguity. It's happening because without the `nonlocal` the interpreter assumes the `i` on the left of the assignment is a local variable (which is how Python works since you don't need to formerly declare variables).